# Greek - Arabic language relation

Tags: syntax, morphology, grammar, greek, arabic

Is there a valid, known link (academic source or even speculation) regarding the Greek and Arabic language, when it comes to syntactic- grammatical or morphological cohesion? I ve only come across Kees Versteedh "Greek elements in Arabic Linguisting thinking" which only impies a connection especially with Aristotelian logic.

Comment: In the Early Islamic era, there were lots of translations from Greek to Arabic. I would not be surprised when some Greek is "shining through" in these translations, and I cannot exclude an influence of the Greek-derived translationese on the evolving Arabic literary language. There are also Greek loan words in Arabic (I am aware of the word for astrolabe). Unfortunately, I have no references on this, so it is only a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Speculated, yes. Accepted, no.

Most linguists agree that there is no relationship between these two languages. Greek is Hellenic which is Indo-European; Arabic is Semitic which is Afro-Asiatic. And while many people have posited links between the IE and AA language families, the idea has never gained widespread approval.

The most common form of this is called the "Nostratic Hypothesis", and also posits links to the Kartvelian, Uralic, Dravidian, Altaic, and Eskimo-Aleut families. But again it's a very fringe theory; I've never met a linguist who actually believed it. The evidence is scarce at best.

And even if the Nostratic hypothesis were true, the relationship between Greek and Arabic would be distant enough that any apparent cognates are more than likely coincidence. Sound changes would have long since erased any similarity at the surface level.